# How to stay on current tab when refreshing html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In html when creating tabs, I can set Paris tab active(hard coded in html with "style="display: block;"). So, when page is loaded the active tab(Paris) would show.

**Problem**

When I click on different tab (London) and hit refresh it shows Paris again. How can I hit refresh and show me the information of the tab that is currently active? Instead of bringing me back to the defined tab. Maybe javascript or jquery can fix my problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>

    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;>
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[Plunker View](https://plnkr.co/edit/lP9d9F7OtAvOuGxD50KD?p=preview)

**Example Image**

[image: Example]

Currently on London, If I hit refresh it should display London's details. Should also work if it were Paris, or Tokyo.

Comment: pass tab name in url as query param

Comment: Save it to a cookie and then read the cookie when you open the page, if the cookie is there then read it and select that tab.

Comment: Hey Mike, just modified the plunker you created to use cookies to store and read back that cookie to select the last selected tab when the page loads. Let me know if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modified plunker that you posted:

```
// your code

    // After you have your tab selected save it to a cookie (change expiration to something that makes sense to you.
    document.cookie = "cityName="+cityName+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2090 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // When  you load the page check if the cookie is there and read it back
  var selectedCity = getCookie("cityName");
  // if there is a selected city then select it. Notice that I added id's to each link with the city name.
  if (selectedCity != ""){
    document.getElementById(selectedCity).click();
  }
});
// Helper function to get the cookie value from the document.cookie string.
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/sCRfBsFRgdQ0wPKI9CMb?p=preview

Hope it helps!

Comment: If I hit refresh on "London" tab I still go back to "Paris" Tab.  I tried removing "style=display:block" from Paris. But when refresh the London tab is no longer active. (Using code you provided and Chrome). But on IE it works as expected.

Comment: You are amazing exactly what I needed working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies to store the current tab value and retrieve it when the page loads. If no cookies found it will select default tab.

You can use this lib for cookies or use javascript default functions.

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var activeCity = Cookies.get('city');
   if (activeCity){
     document.getElementById(activeCity).click();
   }
});

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    Cookies.set('city', cityName, { expires: 7 }); //added new line
}
</script>
```